# mongo $and operator on _id is not working

Tags: mongodb

My data is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53135e99f6af166c18000001"),
    "todos" : [{
            "date" : ISODate("2014-03-02T16:39:06.089Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("53135eaaf6af166c18000002"),
            "completed": false
        }, {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-03-02T16:46:48.717Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("53136078f6af166c18000003"),
            "completed": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query for a specific todo in the the todos array:

```
db.users.find({
    $and : [{
            _id : ObjectId('53135e99f6af166c18000001')
        }, {
            todos : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    _id : ObjectId('53135eaaf6af166c18000002')
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    todos : 1,
    _id: 0
})
```

**Could you explain why it's returning all the todos and what is the correct query?**

Comment: It is returning all todos because you must use elematch in projection too either explicitly or with the `$` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using $ positional projection . It limits the contents of the  field that is included in the query results to contain the first matching element.

```
db.users.find({
    $and : [{
            _id : ObjectId('53135e99f6af166c18000001')
        }, {
            todos : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    _id : ObjectId('53135eaaf6af166c18000002')
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    'todos.$' : 1,
    _id: 0
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more efficient query to get what you want, as you don't need to use either `$and` or `$elemMatch`:

```js
db.users.find({
    _id : ObjectId('53135e99f6af166c18000001'),
    'todos._id' : ObjectId('53135eaaf6af166c18000002')
}, {
    _id: 0,
    'todos.$' : 1
});
```